# Help me for converting give ms access query into MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I am new for mysql, my real data as Mr. & Mrs. Yehuda Sarale Adelist:580 Crown St. #311 11213 
after triggering ms-access query i got Mr. & Mrs. Yehuda Sarale Adelist.
 Ms-Access query define below:

```
SELECT 
CopyExcelHere.Field1, 
Replace([Field2],":",Chr$(13) & Chr$(10)) AS F2, 
Replace([Field3],":",Chr$(13) & Chr$(10)) AS Expr1
FROM CopyExcelHere;
```

I want convert this MS query into mysql query,to get a result Mr. & Mrs. Yehuda Sarale Adelist.
any help will be appricated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this should work

```
select 
  CopyExcelHere.Field1,
  replace(Field2, ':', "\r\n") as F2,
  replace(Field3, ':', "\r\n") as Expr1,
from 
   CopyExcelHere;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.my real data as

Comment: my real data as Mr. & Mrs. Yehuda Sarale Adelist:580 Crown St. #311 11213 
after triggering ms-access query i got Mr. & Mrs. Yehuda Sarale Adelist.
according to your query i get Mr. & Mrs. Yehuda Sarale Adelist 580 Crown St. #311 11213.
please help me to find mysql query that gives me the following result Mr. & Mrs. Yehuda Sarale Adelist

Comment: @sam - You need to update your question to indicate what is inside Field1, Field2, Field3 separately